# How to insert an id as a parameter in method?

Tags: java, android

```
//submit procedure that takes the id of right radio group and the right radio button as input to check the right answer

    private void submit(int right_radiobutton, int Radiogroup, int submission, int right_text) {

    // The selected Radio Group 
    RadioGroup radioGroup = findViewById(Radiogroup);

    //Get the user's name 
    EditText username = findViewById(R.id.name);
    String name = username.getText().toString();

    //Text that displays right or wrong 
    TextView right = findViewById(right_text);

    //The right answer of the question 
    RadioButton right_answer = findViewById(right_radiobutton);
    Boolean isRight = right_answer.isChecked();

    // if statement which know whether the answer is right or wrong 

    if (isRight) {
        right.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        CharSequence text = getString(R.string.Right_Answer) + name;
        int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
        toast.show();
        result++;
    } else {
        if (radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == -1) {
            Context context = getApplicationContext();
            CharSequence text = getString(R.string.question_answer);
            int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
            toast.show();
        } else {
            right.setText(getString(R.string.wrong));
            right.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            //question 1 submit button 
            Button submit1 = findViewById(submission);
            submit1.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            radioGroup.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            Context context = getApplicationContext();
            CharSequence text = getString(R.string.wrong_answer);
            int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
            toast.show();
        }

    }
}
```

This is the code It gives me an error if i try to make the arguments as string saying it must be an int to use it in the findviewbyid
an id data type is string but it gives me an error whenever i try to use it as a string in the findviewbyid

here's the code i used to have when I was stuck , I was typing the ids directly without typing **R.id.idname**

```
public void submit1 (View view){
    submit(right_answer,firstRadioGroup,R.id.submit1,right_text1);
}
```

and here's the code where I'm using the submit after i got the right answer ,Thanks

```
public void submit1 (View view){
    submit(R.id.right_answer,R.id.firstRadioGroup,R.id.submit1,R.id.right_text1);
}
```

Comment: where are you calling the function `submit`

Comment: Can you please add your code where you call the `submit` method?

Comment: @ヅfix  I'm calling it into the submit1 added in the question
it's concerned with the first submission button

Comment: @eselfar Done :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set an id on every View you want to retrieve. 
For instance:

```
<RelativeLayout
  ... >
   <TextView
       android:id="@+id/text_1"
      ... />

   <TextView
       android:id="@+id/text_2"
      ... />
//...
```

Then you can retrieve the views in your Java code using the id

```
TextView tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_1);
TextView tv2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_2);
```

You can't use anything else but an `int` to retrieve a view by id.
If you want to pass the id to a method just do:

```
methodUsingId(R.id.text_1);


public void methodUsingId(@IdRes int viewId){
   //...
}
```

Note that you need to find the view by id only when you want to do something with it. If you have it already you don't need to do that.